# Was it true that Microsoft actually created software for early Apple devices?

Tags: apple, microsoft

Is it really the case that there was a port of Microsoft Word and Excel that was one of the first really successful software to feature on a Apple device? Did Microsoft software actually have a surprisingly positive effect on early Apple products or was it's influence relatively minor?

Comment: They aren't competitors. Microsoft was/is a software business and Apple was/is a hardware business, based on an objective acknowledgment of which market each business actually earns the majority of their profits.

Comment: The original Mac was promoted by Microsoft, with Bill Gates making a personal appearance. See e.g. https://www.pinterest.com/pin/176555247865087618/ and https://www.pinterest.com/pin/462815299191936703/ .

Comment: There's never really been a time when Microsoft hasn't been making software for Apple products.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Microsoft Excel was originally written for the Mac, and released in September 1985 (see [Wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Versions)). It was released for Windows 2 in 1987 (and was in fact bundled with a version of Windows).

Also, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word), Microsoft Word was released for the Mac "in 1985". It had previously existed as a DOS program, being released for the first time on Windows in 1989 (also on Windows 2).

I remember that Microsoft Word and Excel were really very good on the Mac in their early versions, but I don't think they had much of an impact on sales of the Mac platform overall. The initial "killer app" for the Mac platform was "desktop publishing" software. [Aldus PageMaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_PageMaker) was released on the Mac in 1985 (and on Windows in 1987), and [QuarkXPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuarkXPress) was released on the Mac in 1987 (and on Windows 3.1 in 1992).

My own recollection of the period was that the Mac was seen as essential in the 1980s if you needed to do desktop publishing - and that Windows didn't stand a chance at competing until v3.1 was released in 1991, because that version was the first that supported scalable [TrueType fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType). This is because prior to that, Windows relied on raster-based fonts, that didn't scale - meaning that unless you had a copy of the typeface you wanted to use at the exact size you wanted to use it at, everything looked awful. The Mac had always been able to support the printing of [PostScript fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript), and so had a head-start with making text look pretty when printed.

Comment: OK so technically word as we know it today, is a port of an apple program?

Comment: No, Word was a Microsoft package. It was ported to the Mac by Microsoft from DOS, and later ported to Windows. But Excel is a port of a Microsoft package for the Mac. None of them were Apple programs

Comment: I say ‘ported’. That implies a certain amount of code-sharing. I mean that a Mac version of Word was written after they had previously written a DOS and a Xenix version. Similarly, Excel was released on the Mac first, and well-received. It was later released on Windows.

Comment: @ScottEarle it's probable that Word for Windows was based more on the Apple code base than the DOS code base.

Comment: Before TrueType, Windows had not only bitmap-based raster fonts but also scalable stroked fonts.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: At that time Microsoft was just a small company.  It was not until Windows 95 that they took over the marked because people just wanted this and they did a _very_ hard bargain with the hardware vendors.

Comment: Microsoft were very large from the late 1980s. They already had the cash cow of MS-DOS, and they teamed up with IBM to create OS/2 in around 1988. Windows 3 and then 3.1 were huge, followed by Windows NT. But in the early-to-mid 1980s they were large, but only modestly so

Comment: So was Excel available before that for the PC to be run run the DOS command line?

Comment: Word was, but Excel was developed for the Mac first.

Comment: @Acccumulation: _"was Excel available before that for the PC to be run run the DOS command line?"_ -- as noted, no. But before Excel there was Multiplan. It's also significant to note that Multiplan was available on a variety of platforms, using an interpreted runtime (see "p-code") that allowed the same code to run unchanged on those platforms, including MS-DOS. Excel used a similar system and as such, the Windows version isn't so much a "port" as it is basically the exact same code as on Mac, with a thin platform-specific layer between the main application and the OS.

Comment: That’s true today, but I’m pretty sure the prehistoric versions were written for the specific target platforms (i.e. the Mac first, then later rewritten for Windows)

Answer (score 12):

### TL;DR:

It seams as if the Question implies that there was some kind of fiendship between Microsoft and Apple. Such never existed. Microsoft was a major supplier of applications for all ranges of Apple computers and during all time.

---

### Details

> Is it really the case that there was a port of Microsoft Word and Excel that was one of the first really successful software to feature on a Apple device?

No. At least not for Apple devices in general. Then again, for the Macintosh, Microsoft was a major supplier. In fact, [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Early_history) was developed for the Mac, only to appeared for the PC later.

> Did Microsoft software actually have a surprisingly positive effect on early Apple products or was it's influence relatively minor?

Well, it started already early on.  The Apple II's floating point BASIC called [Applesoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applesoft_BASIC), was a Microsoft Basic 2.0. So it came with each and every Apple starting with the II+.

Similar did Microsoft sell the [Softcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-80_SoftCard) with [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) as base for their Z80 products. This shows quite well that there was no imagined shunning of each other, but cooperation. After all, CP/M wasn't a Microsoft product, but made by [Digital Research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Research). So Microsoft payed them royalties (as well as building hardware) to sell their products to Apple customers.

MS even supplied an alternate OS ([Xenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenix)) and applications like [Multiplan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplan) for the [Lisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lisa).

For the later Apple Microsoft was a launching partner, with Multiplan [announced *by Apple*](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/SUL/library/mac/primary/docs/pr1.html) and Microsoft BASIC as some of the first products, already before the release of the Mac. Except, MS used the chance to do a complete redesign of Multiplan, as the code base was just out of hand (more than 100 parallel versions at the time), and replaced Multiplan soon. The new product was called Excel and targeted to beat [Lotus 1-2-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_1-2-3).

In fact, Excel as well as Word development was for long streaks driven by the Mac version, not Windows.

It is known that [Bill Gates was a great fan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO-wR0TyY0M) of the Lisa as well as the Mac. In fact, his original strategy was to get Apple to release a PC version of their OS, or at least licence it to Microsoft. Quite understandable, as having the same OS running cross platform (*1) simplifies application (and language) development a lot. Porting would be a matter of recompilation. MS was an *Application* and *Language* company, not an OS house.

MS had always a great interest in keeping Apple alive as Software for the Mac was a major source of income for MS. At some point they even owned Apple stock as part of a settlement - a cash injection crucial to Apples survival during the late 1990s.

Today Microsoft offers all their major products, from Office all the way to Visual studio - even the edge browser - in Mac versions. Most of them not just simple ports, but quite well integrated with the Mac UI language.

Wiki offers an overview of [Macintosh software published by Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Macintosh_software_published_by_Microsoft).

---

*1 - Also a reason why MS tried to push Xenix as hard at the time.

Comment: Probably not a fiendship but the popular narrative is that they at the very least had a rivalry.

Comment: @NeilMeyer If at all, it's false assumption, or urban legend. They are professional companies and having a dispute about patents and copyright is a normal part these days. Heck, at some point Microsoft owned even a good share in Apple - an investment they made as part of an agreement which helped Apple out of quite some troubled time. MS had always a great interest in keeping Apple alive as it was one major source of income for MS

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure you can get much earlier than Microsoft supplying [Applesoft BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applesoft_BASIC) for the Apple II series in 1977.

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't a port - the first versions of Excel came out on Mac, it didn't appear on Windows until version 2. The first version of Word came out on Xenix but it did appear on Mac very early on. I think it was more important in establishing Microsoft than selling Macs, as Lotus 123 and Mutliplan were the dominant spreadsheets back then.

Comment: When exactly did you stop  having acces to Word and Excel on Apple devices?

Comment: For what it's worth, MultiPlan _was_ a Microsoft product...

Comment: @Neil Meyer I'm not sure that was ever the case? If you look at the Platforms section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office#Platforms

Comment: OK so you can get a derivative of ms office on Apple devices to this day.

Comment: @NeilMeyer All major MS products from Edge and Office all the way to Visual studio are today available for the Mac.

Comment: You might joke that Mac users stopped _wanting_ access to Word for the five-year life of version 6.0, the attempt at a completely unified Windows and Macintosh codebase and UI, but thankfully Microsoft were smart enough to recover from that.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a derivative, it's the Mac version. It has feature parity with the Windows version as far as I know.